# How do I get the second element in a collection, using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a silly question. I have a database and I need to get second item not only the first one. Im opening the first one easy way

`var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).First()`

but I dont know how to open the second one. Im new to C# so only thing I was thinking about was this

`var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).First(-1)`

But that obviously does not work. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you cannot get the second element with First(), maybe you should try to get List of SourceLogs, and then use index 1 to get second element. Or use a specific condition that describe the second element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) method to jump over the first and take the one after:

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(...).Skip(1).First();
```

What Skip does is create a new IEnumerable containing all items except the first. Then, you take the First() of that new IEnumerable.

Comment: In fact there is already a LINQ method for this exact thing: `ElementAt`. Check my answer below as well .

Answer (score 8):

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).ElementAt(1);
```

Comment: This will select the third instead of the second item

Comment: Sure, you're right. I made a change.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).OrderBy(a => a.SourceID).Skip(1);
```

Update: If you want to get just second item in the list, you can add `.First()` at the end of the query:

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).OrderBy(a => a.SourceID).Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: Important to note that this won't return a single item, but an IEnumerable.with one item.

Answer (score 1):

You can just skip the first one and take first from it.

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).Skip(1).First()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
var source = _context.SourceLogs.Where(a => a.SourceID == user.ID).ToList();
```

Then query the source list at convenience

Comment: That's not a good general solution. This would pull the entire list of SourceLogs that match the SourceId from the database, instead of just the first of them.

Comment: That's why I said 'at convenience', which would minimize calls to context.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan `Skip` would do the same, so this not not the actual problem. However it does not extract the second item from the list